# How can I restrict my collaborator's push requests so that I can verify them?

Tags: git

I created a private repository for a project. Now, I am thinking of adding a collaborator. But I wish to verify what he pushes on to the repository. I want to gain control on the changes made. How can I do that? I am quite new to Git, and so I don't know if Branches can solve this problem. But I still want to verify before making changes to the master branch.

Comment: There are no technical solution to *every* social problem. I recommend *speaking* with your collaborator, and agree on *conventions* (e.g. about branches). Don't forget to read the [documentation of git](http://git-scm.com/doc)

Comment: read about merge request and protected branches. you will get an idea what you need !!

Comment: Using a tool like github and Bitbucket allow control over such things. Instead of verifying each push, you would force the contributor to submit a pull-request.

Answer (score 1):

If you use GitHub, this is easier if the repository is located in an organisation (and you can do it with the free plan).

Different access levels for collabrators are only available for organisations and protected branches for private repositories require the paid plan for private repositories anyways. Protected branches also do not allow to be configured at a per-user level if the repository is owned by an individual account and not an organisation.

---

### hooks (if you are hosting the git server yourself)

You could create a server-side hook that is run whenever someone pushes. You can run whatever checks you want to, there.

However, this is only possible if you host the remote repository by yourself as servers like GitHub do not allow this but you can use other methods.

### fork (another repository)

The most common approach is not to give him collabrator access but let him work on a fork. He can then submit his work to you with a pull request or similar.

You can then decide whether you want to integrate (merge) this pull request into your main repository.

If the repository is located in an organisation, you can configure access levels for each person using the `Manage Access` option.

[image: manage access page]

He can then fork the repository using the top right `fork` button.

[image: fork button]

After making changes, he can submit a Pull Request using the `Pull Request` button.

[image: pull request button]

As he does not have `write` access, he cannot merge the pull request himself and you can review it.

[image: Only you can merge the pull request]

Git also provides utilities for sending such changes per e-mail if you prefer that over pull requests.

### protected branches

Another option is to use protected branches (this is specific for GitHub but there are other possibilities for other servers).

You can restrict access to the master branch to that contributor and let him submit a pull request every time. You can then review and merge it whenever you want.

This is possible by creating a branch-protection rule for the `master` branch (and what branches you want to protect) and restrict who can push to these branches.

Note that you can also configure that a review is required before pushing to that branch and you can also use wildcards for the branch name.

[image: restrict per-branch push access]

Comment: As I indicated earlier by using the term private repo, this project is confidential. But I have to maintain some level of control here. Can people fork my private repository? How do I do that? And how can I manage to make him submit pull requests? What settings would I need to change? Can you guide me on which part of the git documentation to read since I am not habituated with reading documentation as I am still in university? @dan1st

Comment: Yes, private forks are possible but (with GitHub) you will need to use protected branches (if you do not have an organisation) in order to restrict access on the repository. As I mentioned, he can also send you the changes per email so that you can merge it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try it as per the suggestion. If I get stuck, I will mention you here again